# Using django and redmine together on the same server

Tags: django, apache, redmine

I'm searching for a way to configure apache correctly so that my django user can add bug in redmine without setting up multiple server. I have two half working apache configuration  :

The classic one :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/my_project/settings/wsgi.py
```

The django server can run, but if I try to call a redmine url, it makes an error 404.

And I tried to use a regex to protect the Redmine url pattern from Django :

```
WSGIScriptAlias ^\/(?!redmine(.*)) /home/my_project/settings/wsgi.py
```

For this one Redmine works, but I get the default apache page as if the configuration was'nt done for all the Django URL.

Is there something wrong with my regex ? Is this the wrong approach to this problem ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [this server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/147838/how-to-let-mod-wsgi-only-handle-certain-urls-under-apache), you should use **WSGIScriptAliasMatch** :

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/(?!redmine) /home/my_project/settings/wsgi.py
```